# Software center reinstallation fails

Tags: installation, software-center

```
Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.
INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser-layer.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
Software catalog update was successful.
```

That is what i got when reinstalling my software center. I tried to reinstall it after there was a problem doing installations via it. Now, this came, and well, what is the next step to do in order to get it work again? Its boring to always have to use the terminal for installations.

This is the terminal output when attempting to install Audacity in my software center: http://pastebin.com/vKc2EXG0

EDIT:
I opened a bug report with this issue.

The **/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser.desktop:** [Here.](http://pastebin.com/cBm1ujxp) , existed.
The other files didnt exist/was empty

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 12.10 is my current version

Comment: Also, please post your `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser.desktop`, `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser-layer.desktop`, and `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop` files.

Comment: The `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser.desktop` :
http://pastebin.com/cBm1ujxp

The other files didnt exist/was empty.

Comment: Try running `sudo update-desktop-database`. Then try installing.

Comment: Forgot to mention ; when trying to click `install`, a window pops up saying `system program problem detected. Do you want to Report this problem now?`
And the command did not help me make programs get installed, sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8443/discussion-between-dennorske-and-green7)

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and give us the output:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: same as above this time too. Have a look here: http://pastebin.com/y0N6kVaY

Comment: run `sudo apt-get remove --purge sonic-visualiser`

Comment: `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:` --Alot of packages--
So, what now ?

Comment: unistall them too, we can learn from fails..